# How to compile a java program , while keeping a windows-1252 encoding filename?

Tags: java, compilation, character-encoding

Compiling a java program which has different encoding , works with the following line : "`javac -encoding windows-1252 MyClass.java"` , however if I try to accomplish the same thing , while the class name also special characters in it , it , javac fails to identify it .So I am looking for ways to accomplish this : `"javac -encoding windows-1252 MyCláss.java"`.I run Ubuntu 16.

Comment: What is the error or symptom when you ty to compile `MyCláss.java` ?

Comment: It simply doesn’t think it exists , if I were to use the command ls , it would list both versions of MyClass , javac on the other hand , would list only the one without special characters

Comment: The `-encoding` flag is for the *content* of the file, not the name of the file. (As an aside, I'd *strongly* encourage you to use a platform-agnostic encoding, ideally UTF-8, to make this sort of thing easier to handle.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that’s what I usually do , however I’ve got a task to do this , and renaming the file would be considered cheating , and my googling had no results .

Comment: I assumed you were compiling on Windows since you're using a windows encoding, but can I confirm that this is the case? What filesystem are you using?

Comment: This sounds like you've got a *very* strange assignment which has little to do with real life. Please could you give more context? (It's still not clear to me whether the problem is with the filename or the content - as I said before, `-encoding` has nothing to do with the filename, as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: @JonSkeet My task is to compile and run a java project which has classes which are named using Hungarian letters(ISO8852-1) and these special letters appear in the context too. Once unzipped (the project) the filenames which had the special character in them were automatically renamed , if I try compiling now , it says the class name doesn’t match the class name , if I change the filename , javac doesn’t recognize it

Comment: @gameerik: I'm not sure what encoding zip files use for their filenames, but if they look okay on the console, it may well be okay. I would edit the file to make sure that the *content* is in UTF-8 as a universally available encoding. (I'd also seriously consider complaining to whoever's setting the task that this isn't a good way of learning Java...)

Comment: @JonSkeet it wasn’t utf8 by default , I converted it (read the discussion under the answer ) but same result

Comment: Please update the question with the progress, including the *precise* error message.

Comment: It's neither here nor there if the class names are recognizable as Hungarian. Once you've passed the correct file character encoding to javac, all characters are converted to Unicode. Class names then have to satisfy Java rules. So, ask whoever gave you the files which encoding they use. That's no different than receiving any text file.